# How can I determine whether a path is filesystem or registry?

Tags: powershell

I'm making a function which can take a argument which can be either filesystem or registry path. e.g.

```
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows'
```

I don't want to divide them by named argument but their interfaces aren't compatible. How can I classify them?

Comment: If there's one character before the colon? If the part before the colon is in `(get-psprovider filesystem).drives.name`? If `(get-item $x).GetType()` is a DirectoryInfo vs a RegistryKey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method (`$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath`) to do that. It have overload, which allows you to extract PowerShell provider and PowerShell drive info from path.

```
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows' |
ForEach-Object { $Provider = $null } {
    [void]$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($_, [ref]$Provider, [ref]$null)
    $Provider
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands tell you the types:

```
(Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run').GetType().Name # returns RegistryKey
(Get-Item 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows').GetType().Name # returns DirectoryInfo
```

...or another way of getting the same info...

```
$item = Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
$item.GetType().Name # returns RegistryKey

$item = Get-Item 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows'
$item.GetType().Name # returns DirectoryInfo
```

Comment: What if item with this path does not exist?

Comment: `Test-Path 'path_string'`

Comment: Does `Test-Path` say, which provider it is?

Comment: No. `Test-Path` tests for existence. Try using `Get-Help` :). e.g. `Get-Help Test-Path`

Comment: Then returning to my original question: "What if item with this path does not exist?". How do you get provider in this case?

Comment: True, @PetSerAl, your response to the OPs post works. Add as an answer and I'll upvote.